# How to handle validation scripts distributed in diferents files in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I have several modules that export a function that return true or false when the payload is valid or not. I also have a config file in JSON in which I specify the name of the validator script to use depending on the payload type:

```
[
  {
    "boardVersion": "1",
    "availableInterfaces": [
      { "name": "digital", "validator": "digitalV1" },
      { "name": "analog", "validator": "analogV1" },
    ]
  }
]
```

And for example inside digitalv1.js I have something like:

```
import validator from 'validator';

module.exports = (value) => {
    validator.isInt(value, {min: 0, max: 3});
};
```

And finally, a controller that gets the payload from ExpressJS and depending on the endpoint called it decides what validator to use. The thing now is how can I load the validator in the controller.

There are 2 approaches that come to my mind:

1. In the controller, I require every validator and push them in a key-value array (or object), in which the key is the name of the validator and the value the validator itself.
2. Instead of defining a validator name in the JSON file I could just put the file path in the file system and just require the file when I need it.

I there a better/cleaner way to approach this? Feel free to suggest even a different architecture. The idea though is to keep validators separated for code cleanness sake.

Comment: Since you are using ES6 import syntax, I suggest you use the export syntax too by replacing `module.exports = ` to `export default` or `export`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **option 1**, but with a "barrel module", which imports the validators, and attaches them onto an array or object.  Then, any module that needs the validators can just import the main module, and use the provided lookup function, index, or key to get the validator they need.

Be careful of circular dependencies: if you have them, you can use `module.exports.x =` and Node will handle them correctly (Note: I'm not sure if this is necessary with ES6 modules, which handle circular dependencies a little differently; just something to be on guard for).

Since the knowledge to create this "barrel module" already exists in your JSON, you could watch your JSON file in your build process, and **automatically generate** this barrel module if any of the file associations change, throw an error if a specified module is not found at a certain file path, etc.